# How to pass value from Fb.api to Fb.ui

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to exclude friend on invite dialog request and function looklike

```
duplicate:function(){
   var responsive = '';
    FB.api(
      {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query:'SELECT uid,name  FROM user WHERE uid IN \n\
         (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1 '
      },
      function(response) { 
         responsive = response;} 
  );
      return responsive;
}, 

onInviteClick: function(responsive) {
            FB.ui(  {
                method: 'apprequests',
                title: 'Popsecret ป็อบคอร์นแสนอร่อย',
                exclude_ids: responsive
                message: 'ชวนคุณกดไลท์เพื่อลุ้นรับไอแพดเเละของรางวัลอีกมากมาย',
                max_recipients: 15
            } , function(response) {
        if (response !== null) {

            $.post(Site.inviteCallbackURL, response, function(res) {

            });
        }
    });
```

and I can't pass data from duplicate to onInviteClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move var `responsive = '';` from function into global scope. Then you can access it from all other functions. Keep in mind, that the API call is asynchronous, so you need to wait for the completion of the request ([jQuery Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) might help you there)